# How to set up live reloading with webpack-encore in a Symfony project?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I have created a Symfony full web app with the given command `symfony new app --webapp`. It came with [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) configured with `webpack-encore`. I can have my assets compiled with `npm run watch`. But the browser don't reload automatically  when my I make changes. I have tried [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) following Symfony's official documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/dev-server.html), but didn't work.

webpack.config.js (I just removed the comments):

```js
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
 if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
        Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
    }
Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabel((config) => {
       config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
     })
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })
    ;
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

package.json:

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.0.0",
        "@symfony/stimulus-bridge": "^3.0.0",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.7.0",
        "core-js": "^3.0.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up live reloading with `webpack-encore` in a Symfony project with the help of [Browsersync](https://browsersync.io). Follow the below steps carefully and you will be good to go.

1. Step one:

```
npm i browser-sync-webpack-plugin browser-sync dotenv --save-dev
```

2. Edit `webpack.config.js` (there are comments for the lines to add):

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
require("dotenv").config(); // Line to add
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require("browser-sync-webpack-plugin"); // Line to add
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}
Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // Entry to add 
    .addPlugin(new BrowserSyncPlugin(
        {
            host: "localhost",
            port: 3000,
            proxy: process.env.PROXY,
            files: [
                {
                    match: ["src/*.php"],
                },
                {
                    match: ["templates/*.twig"],
                },
                {
                    match: ["assets/*.js"],
                },
                {
                    match: ["assets/*.css"],
                },
            ],
            notify: false,
        },

        {

            reload: true,
        }
    ))

;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

3. Add the line below inside your `.env` (the url should be the one you get when you run `symfony serve`):

```
# The url should be the one you get when you run symfony serve
PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

4. Open a terminal in your project root folder and run:

```
symfony serve
```

5. Open a second terminal in your project root folder and run:

```
npm run watch
```

Answer (score 2):

Id recommend using webpack's built-in liveReload.

You can enable it in encore with the `--live-reload` flag.
e.g. `encore dev-server --live-reload`

To run the dev-server, you would run `npm run dev-server` instead of `npm run watch`

#### Live reload on twig / php file changes.

If you want to reload on twig changes, you can use `webpack.devServer.watchFiles.paths`
See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwatchfiles

I dont have the exact syntax, but in yourwebpack.config.js file, you can

```js
// webpack.config.js
// ...

Encore
    // ...

    .configureDevServerOptions(options => {
        options.watchFiles = {
            paths: ['src/**/*.php', 'templates/**/*'],
        }
    })
;
```

Comment: Hi jonnyeom! With this, do you get a live reload when you change a twig file for example?

Comment: Not immediately. But I believe you can set that up.
I added extra info above for that.